# Angular on video load event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, html5-video

I'm still trying to understand angular...

Basically, I have an html5 video and I want to listen to the `onloadeddata` event (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onloadeddata.asp).

This is what I have:

html:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loaded-data loop style="display: none;">
  <source src="videos/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="videos/example.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('loadedData', function () {
    return function ($scope, $element) {
      $element.addEventListener("loadeddata", function () {
        console.log('test'); // never calls
      });
    }
});
```

Is this the correct way of handling this? For some reason, the event listener never gets called.

I've also tried

```
$element.bind('loadedData', function () {
    console.log('test');
});
```

but it also doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! Looks like I need to use:

```
$element[0].addEventListener(...)
```

Instead of:

```
$element.addEventListener(...)
```

Comment: Yes, but the bottom line is to use directives to add and customize angular's event handling

Answer (score 0):

```
$element.on('loadeddata', function (event) {
   var width = $element[0].videoWidth;
}
```

'loadeddata' works for me 'loadedData' does not